# Web app starting and stopping immediately

Tags: html, css, go, web-applications

I am creating a web app in Go. Im working in the Login and Home page now. And I am able to login to the app and see my home page just fine. Now I am trying to add styles to the Login Page. But it seems that I did (??) something that causes the app to start and immediatelly shutdown without throwing any kind of errors, warnings or panics.

Im not very sure what could be happening. The last thing I did was adding a general CSS file to my login page. But even removing that does not fix the issue.

This is my main method:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/Matias-Barrios/QuizApp/config"
    "github.com/Matias-Barrios/QuizApp/router"
)

func main() {
    envF := config.EnvironmentFetcher{}
    port, err := envF.GetValue("PORT")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
    log.Println("Starting app in port : ", port)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, router.GetRouter())
}
```

And this is my router.go file :

```
package router

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/Matias-Barrios/QuizApp/config"
)

var APP_KEY string

func init() {
    var err error
    envF := config.EnvironmentFetcher{}
    APP_KEY, err = envF.GetValue("APP_KEY")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
}

// GetRouter :
func GetRouter() *http.ServeMux {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/login", loginHandler)
    mux.Handle("/index", AuthMiddleware(http.HandlerFunc(indexHandler)))
    mux.HandleFunc("/auth", TokenHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", faviconHandler)

    // Static files handling
    mux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
    return mux
}
```

Can someone see something that might cause such an issue?
When I start the app I get the console output just fine and then immediately stops :

```
matias@QuizApp (master)
 $ APP_KEY="secret" PORT="3000" go run main.go 
2020/02/08 23:51:00 Starting app in port :  3000
matias@QuizApp (master)
 $
```

#### Note :

I was not even modifying any **.go* files when this started happening. I was simply modifying the *html* and *css* files.

#### Note 2:

I found these two processes were running  in the background with *ps* :

```
matias    2877  3499  0 23:27 ?        00:00:00 /home/matias/go/bin/dlv debug --headless=true --listen=127.0.0.1:11449 --api-version=2
matias    2953  2877  0 23:27 ?        00:00:00 /home/matias/go/src/github.com/Matias-Barrios/QuizApp/__debug_bin
```

I guessed they were the culprit and yes, now my app works. Im using VS Code, maybe a bug on it?

Comment: Hi, ListenAndServe returns an error, you could print the returned error to verify if it provides more info. `ListenAndServe always returns a non-nil error. After Shutdown or Close, the returned error is ErrServerClosed.`. Regards.

Comment: Thanks Ill implement that for the next time this happens. @dime2lo

Comment: I am not sure if you had the same problem, but it reminds me of something I had one in a while. My app crashed of i forcefully closed it. The application seemed to be closed complete but the port I used was still blocket. After reboot or choosing another port everything worked just fine.